# Combine these mySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I need to combine these queries, so i get back a list of months, with a new total, and returning total (to track new and returning users). I currently have these two queries below. The first counts devices which are new (detection freq), the second counts as returning. I want to output the results so it's a table with rows for each month, then two columns with New, and Returning data.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (mac) ) AS new,
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_time ) AS month
FROM detected_devices
WHERE client_id = 11
AND venue_id = 1
AND detection_frequency = 1
GROUP BY month

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (mac) ) AS returning,
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_time ) AS month
FROM detected_devices
WHERE client_id = 11
AND venue_id = 1
AND detection_frequency > 1
GROUP BY month
```

I have had a look around but not found any information on how this can be done with aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
SELECT t1.month, t1.new, t2.returning FROM (query 1) as t1, (query 2) as t2 where t1.month = t2.month;
```

(or a join, depending on what you prefer).

Comment: Super. Thank you very much! Solved a headache.

Answer (score 0):

This only gives you one row with two columns, but should give you an idea of how you can use aliases

```
SELECT
A.new,
B.returning
FROM
(SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (mac) ) AS new,
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_time ) AS month
FROM detected_devices
WHERE client_id = 11
AND venue_id = 1
AND detection_frequency = 1
GROUP BY month) A,
(SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (mac) ) AS returning,
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_time ) AS month
FROM detected_devices
WHERE client_id = 11
AND venue_id = 1
AND detection_frequency > 1
GROUP BY month) B
```